# Python TSP Held-Karp algorithm

Tags: python, graph, networkx, traveling-salesman

I'm trying to implement Held-Karp in Python but it doesn't seem to be working. There are two differences in my problem from the classical TSP problem (as used in the description of the H-K algorithm I found in the web):
- I don't need to return to the original node. I think this is called a Hamiltonian cycle but I'm not very familiar with graph algorithms so I'm not entirely sure. Each city needs to be visited once as in TSP
- Some edges in the graph are missing

I used networkx and created this function:

```
def hk(nodes,Graph,start_node, total_ops, min_weight = 9999999,min_result = []):
nodes.remove(start_node)
# removes the current node from the set of nodes
for next_node in nodes:

    total_ops += 1
    current_weight = 0
    try:
        current_weight += Graph[start_node][next_node]["weight"]
        # checks if there's an edge between the current node and the next node
# If there's an edge, adds the edge weight
    except:
        continue
    sub_result = []
    if len(nodes) > 1:
        new_nodes = set(nodes)
        sub_result,sub_weight,total_ops = hk(new_nodes,Graph,next_node, total_ops) 
#calculates the minimum weight of the remaining tree
        current_weight += sub_weight
    if current_weight < min_weight:
# if the weight of the tree is below the minimum weight, update minimum weight
        min_weight = current_weight
        min_result = [next_node] + sub_result
return min_result,min_weight,total_ops
```

But something is clearly wrong as I'm expecting O(n ** 2 * 2 ** n) complexity but am getting O(n!) instead, same as for the brute force method (trying all combinations one by one). Clearly, there's an error in my implementation.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more explanation of what your code is trying to do? Held-Karp involves finding a minimum 1-tree -- where is that in your code? Where are the weights that are placed on the nodes -- are those already baked into the `Graph`?

Comment: To address your questions about terminology, a Hamiltonian cycle is a cycle that visits every node exactly once. Every TSP tour is a cycle. The TSP problem is the problem of finding the minimum-length Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: You can model the missing edges by setting their distance to infinity. You can convert your problem (no return leg) to a standard TSP (return to start node) by setting the length of the edge from every node back to node 1 equal to a constant that is larger than the largest edge in the network.

Comment: I have added some comments to the code. Sorry if my terminology is wrong. Yes, the weights are already baked into the graph.

Comment: Are you just trying to find the optimal 1-tree on a given network?

Comment: In that case it should not be O(n ** 2 2 ** n) *or* O(n!) -- it is polynomial. Just find a minimum spanning tree on nodes {2,...,n} (assuming you want the 1-tree "rooted" at node 1) using Kruskal's or Prim's algorithm; then add the two shortest edges from node 1.

Comment: I implemented Kruskal but that's not what I want - I want each node to be visited just once. That's a TSP, I guess.

Comment: I just realized that you are trying to implement Held and Karp's **DP** for the TSP. Usually when people say "Held-Karp" they are referring to their **lower bound** for TSP, which involves these things called 1-trees. So ignore my last comment. I'm going to punt this one back. If I have a chance I'll take a closer look at some point.